# WebRequest 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: c#, webrequest

Eai galera, estou com dificuldade em entender o porque está dando gateway timeout em um request, pois sendo que testei por cURL e foi normal, estou utilizando Basic Auth.
Segue:

```
            var authorization = "apikey:";
            HttpWebRequest wbRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.konduto.com/v1/orders/0");            
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };            
            wbRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", authorization);
            wbRequest.Method = "GET";                  
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)wbRequest.GetResponse();
            var stringFinally = "";
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                stringFinally = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Ao dar getResponse ele me volta :

```
The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso e como eu poderia resolver, pois via cURL o GET funciona normal.

Comment: `wbRequest.Timeout = timeout;` deve funcionar.

Comment: O problema parece ser o local acessado (talvez você tenha alguma dificuldade por causa da sua internet). O timeout *default* é de 100 segundos, Já acho até muito. Pode ser até o jeito de usar mas só com estas informações não dá para saber. O código parece estar ok em relação a isto (como sempre a maioria dos códigos postados aqui não fazem tudo o que devem para serem robustos, mas isto é outra coisa). Você tentou acessar sem este código? Tenho minhas dúvidas se essa autorização é necessária. Eu usei sem nada e foi.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer um teste, não sei se há algum problema com o ambiente que tenho mas se eu acessar no navegador sem passar um chave de API retorna um resultado imediato. Sem tento por código sem autorização, dá erro de autorização. Não faz muito sentido já que pelo navegador funciona. E realmente quando coloca a autorização ele não consegue retornar nada em tempo hábil. Isto indica que este tipo de autorização está causando problema. Veja na documentação se existe alguma outra forma de fazer isto. É complicado responder perguntas sobre APIs muito específicas.

Comment: @WisnerOliveira apaga isto rápido. A não ser que isto seja temporário, não vá te causar problemas (mesmo) não coloque informação privativa na internet. Com o cURL você passa esta chave de e faz o processo de autorização ou não? Isto está com cara de algum problema deles ou uso errado da API, não sei se alguém aqui conseguiria ajudar. Eles fornecem suporte?

Comment: @bigown a key é temporária, eu revogo ela e pego outra e sim eu passo via curl também, segue script: 
curl -u "apikey" -X GET "https://api.konduto.com/v1/orders/0"

Comment: Já tentou usar `HTTPClient`?

Comment: @bigown sim, já tentei.

Comment: @bigown o retorno quando sai pelo cURL vem assim : 
{"status":"error","message":{"where":"/","why":{"expected":"order (0) to exist","found":"order (0) does not exist"}}}

certinho

Comment: É o que eu consegui pelo navegador sem autorização, sem nada. Por isto é estranho. Porque eu acho que tem algo erro no uso da API, provavelmente tem que passar algo mais para funcionar. Mas por outro lado deveria funcionar sem autorização também, funciona no navegador.

Comment: @bigown sério ? o.o qual o retorno que você obtêm pelo navegador ? o único retorno que pelo navegador eu tenho é esse : 
{"status":"error","message":{"where":"/","why":{"expected":"Authentic API key.","found":"Unauthentic API key."}}}

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20767/discussion-between-wisner-oliveira-and-bigown).

Comment: É verdade, já tinha esquecido. Mas no te que isto é um retorno real, não é um erro de autorização do navegador. Só você sabe o que fazer com isto, o navegador não sabe. É claro que pode ser que também tenha um erro de autorização que eu não vi (não tenho como ver agora). Ainda acho que você precisará de suporte específico para ver o que falta enviar. Mas não tenho experiência com estes componentes, então pode ter um problema óbvio que eu não estou percebendo.

Comment: Entendi, vou procurar o suporte da API e ver com eles se falta algo, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
var authorization = "apikey:";
HttpWebRequest wbRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.konduto.com/v1/orders/0");
wbRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

string apiKey = Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authorization));
wbRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", apiKey);
wbRequest.Method = "GET";
try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)wbRequest.GetResponse(); 
    var stringFinally = "";
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        stringFinally = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
 }
 catch (WebException ex)
 {
     var stringFinallyException = "";
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
     {
          stringFinallyException = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
 }
```

Joguei a API key para **Base64**. O erro *504 gateway timeout* é que a requisição ainda nem foi validada pois o *basic Auth* estava indo puro tipo *XYZXYZXYZX:* e ele tem que ir em **Base64**.